# Zend url view helper - keeping existing params in a reversed route

Tags: php, zend-framework, url-routing

At the moment in my ZF project have a URL structure like this:

```
/news/index/news_page/1/blog_page/2
```

When I generate my pagination I use the URL helper as follows:

```
<?php echo $this->url(array('blog_page'=>3)); ?>
```

Which generates a URL like this:

```
/news/index/news_page/1/blog_page/3
```

What I'd like to do is use a custom route to have nicer URLs, something like this:

```
new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
  'news/:news_page/:blog_page', 
  array('controller' => 'news', 'action' => 'index')
);
```

However, when I try an use this route in the view helper:

```
<?php echo $this->url(array('blog_page'=>3), 'newsIndex'); ?>
```

It throws an error because I've not specified news_page in the params.

How can I get around this, and tell the url helper to use the 'current' values for these params?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The url helper will use the an existing parameter if it exists in the current request. It seems as if, in your particular case, the `news_page` param is not set in the request object. Setting a default value for the `news_page` parameter in your route should solve your problem.

So, your route definition should look something like this:

```
new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
  'news/:news_page/:blog_page', 
  array('controller' => 'news', 'action' => 'index', 'news_page' => 1)
);
```

Comment: Thanks Jason, that's exactly what was happening.